# How to use pure pipe to only trigger re-rendering when single object is added/removed from array Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom pipe that receives an array of objects. This pipes iterates over each object in the array, and modifies that objects 'name' property to limit number of characters that get displayed:

```
`
  transform(gearImages: GearImage[]): GearImage[] {         
    let viewImagesArr: GearImage[] = [];    

    for (let index = 0; index < gearImages.length; index++) {
      let viewImage = Object.assign({}, gearImages[index]);
      viewImage.name = viewImage.name.slice(0, 27);
      viewImagesArr = [...viewImagesArr, viewImage];
    }
    return viewImagesArr;
  }
`
```

In the HTML template I use it like this:

```
`
 *ngFor="let gearImage of gearItemImages | gearImageView">{{ gearImage.name }}
`
```

User can add items to the array, and remove. I want to animate the addition and removal of items in the array. This all works well with the exception that when user adds or removes items, the entire array gets re-rendered instead of individual items.  I understand that this pipe is a pure pipe, so it will only re-render when a reference changes. Is it possible to create a pure pipe, that only modifies the objects' properties for the view, and re-renders when single items are added or removed from the array?

I really dont like the fact that I have to trim the actual name of the object `{name: 'superLongNameThatIWantToKeepOnlyTrimForVIew'}`. I would like to save the actual name, and trim just the view name

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is `trackBy` see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description

```
 *ngFor="let gearImage of gearItemImages; trackBy:trackByfn | gearImageView">{{ gearImage.name }}
```

```
public trackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.id
}
```

This will tell Angular to track your dom element by the item's id, so angular doesn't re-render that dom element unless the id changes. so array modifications won't re-render the entire list